# Can I convert the argument of a function into its own variable's name?

Tags: javascript

So I want to have something like this:

```
function trace(variable){
    console.log(variables_name.toString()+":"+variable);
}
```

Is this possible, and if so, how can I invoke/print the variable's name?

This way I can succinctly write `trace(a_variable)` and have a good idea of what it is without having to write `console.log("variable name: "+ variable);`

Comment: No. Argument expressions in function calls are evaluated before the call is made. All that's passed to the function is a copy of the value of the expression.

Comment: Is there some way to circumvent this by instead giving the function some kind of signature for the variable instead of a copy of its value?

Comment: you don't always care about argument names, you can simply use `arguments` object in your method.

Comment: There's no way that's not simpler than the `console.log()` example you gave. You'd have to explicitly pass the variable name as a string, and that's pretty much what you're doing by directly calling `console.log()`.

Comment: In this case you could write a preprocessor that converts all `trace(foo)` calls to `console.log('foo:', foo);`. You might even get away with using a regular expression for that. But you certainly cannot do that at runtime.

Comment: Side note: Don't concatenate the value, otherwise you don't get useful output for complex values, like objects. Pass the value as argument to `console.log`: `console.log("variable name:", variable);`

Comment: @Felix Kling I have no experience writing preprocessors, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a map:

```
function trace(variableMap){
    for (var key in variableMap){
        console.log(key+":"+variableMap[key]);
    }
}

trace ({someVar : someVar});
```

Since a mod accepted this answer for OP I'll go ahead and add that simply doing

```
trace({someVar});
```

Also seems to work.  This notation depends on ECMAScript 6 is called the [Object Literal Property Value Shorthand](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html).

Comment: If the environment supports it, one could even use *short object notation*: `trace({someVar}),` which gets the OP 99% to where they want.

Comment: Unfortunately if I want to pass something like Object.variable I have to declare it before-hand.  for instance `var len = Array.length; trace({len});`

Comment: Indeed `trace({someVar})` works in all of my use-cases.

Comment: @Csteele5 You could do `trace({"Array.length": Array.length})`

Comment: @FelixKling what environment doesn't support it?

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_properties

Comment: So in those cases wwhich do not support shorthand, I just have to use `{someVar:someVar}`?

Comment: You're missing the point.  You don't control the users, you have to make a decision to either be backward compatible, or bleeding edge.